# Xamarin Layout design issues with rotation

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am really new to Xaml development, hence this question.

I am trying to build a screen like below in the Xamarin forms :

[image: Layout]

I have tried to use following code

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="Gray">
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Top!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Blue">
        <!-- middle controls -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Middle!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    </StackLayout>
    <RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Overlay.Bottom!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

however I am not getting the result, even if it get it to work partially, it fails when the screen is rotated.

Can someone please help me with the `xaml` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code exactly renders what you want.

```
<Grid Padding="10" BackgroundColor="Blue">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ContentView Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="LightGray">
            <Label Text="TopPanel" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </ContentView>
        <ContentView Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Orange">
            <Label Text="Fill Rest Panel" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </ContentView>
    </Grid>
    <ContentView Margin="10" HeightRequest="50" VerticalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Green">
        <Label Text="Overlay Bottom Panel" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </ContentView>
</Grid>
```

Refer to the below image for the output.

[image: Overlay with Grid]

Comment: @Kiran, If my reply helps you, please remember to mark my reply as an answer. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

From shared code , it can not realize what your want . Because `RelativeLayout` is contained in `StackLayout` , you should make the `RelativeLayout` as the root layout in Xaml . Then it can show the effects of `RelativeLayout`.

Therefore ,if you are considering about using **[Xamarin.Forms RelativeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout)** to realzie it , you can have a look at the follow code :

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ContentView x:Name="FirstContent"
                    BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
                    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.02,Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.02,Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.96,Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.18,Constant=0}">
        <Label Text="Top Panel"
                FontSize="Large"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </ContentView>
    <ContentView x:Name="SecondContent"
                    BackgroundColor="SandyBrown"
                    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.02,Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.22,Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=0.96,Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.76,Constant=0}">
        <Label Text="Fill Rest Panel"
                FontSize="Large"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </ContentView>

    <ContentView x:Name="ThirdContent"
                    BackgroundColor="ForestGreen"
                    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=SecondContent,Property=Width,Factor=0.1,Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=SecondContent,Property=Height,Factor=1.13,Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=.8,Constant=0}"
                    RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.10,Constant=0}">
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Overlay.Bottom!"
                FontSize="Large"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </ContentView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works and so does the one suggested by @Harikrishnan. Can you please help me understand whats the difference between these 2 options?

Comment: @Kiran Okey . The difference between them is that when there are multiple overlapping views in the layout, using RelativeLayout can more accurately and conveniently add other views to the required position, and it will not mess up the layout code, but Grid cannot completely do it. such. Also, when your device screen size is varied or the horizontal and vertical screens are switched, the RelativeLayout can be displayed in proportion to the parent view, but the Grid cannot completely do so.

Comment: @Kiran In the current layout you need, only two views overlap, which doesn't look too different for Grid and RelativeLayout. RelativeLayout is necessary if you need more complex views that overlap later.

Comment: Thanks!, this really helps me understand.